# VB Parallel.ForEach with different subroutines

Tags: vb.net

I currently have test code that is made up of a number of distinct subroutines. I have a main routine that calls each one in order... I then changed the code to support using `ThreadPool`, and add each test routine to the cue.
Next step for me is to use the `Parallel.ForEach`, but each example I found contains a single subroutine that is called, rather than my distinct routines.

**Trivial Example-sequential**

```
Sub Main
    Test1()
    Test2()
    Test3()
End Sub
```

**Example - ThreadPool**

```
Sub Main
    Dim compportthreads As Int32
    Dim UnusedThreads As Int32
    Dim totalthreads As Int32

    System.Threading.ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(totalthreads, compportthreads)
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf Test1)
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf Test2)
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf Test3)

    Do
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(UnusedThreads, compportthreads)
    Loop Until UnusedThreads = totalthreads
End Sub
```

**Example 3 - Parallel.ForEach**

```
???
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish or what your question is.

Comment: I don't think that Parallel.ForEach is going to do what you think it is going to do. And the ThreadPool example is unclear as to the intent of the Do ... Loop.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. How do I use Parallel.ForEach with the 3 different subroutines? (I actually have around 500 distinct subroutines I need to run)

Comment: I found that, when using the ThreadPool, I needed to have a Do..Loop to run. That Loop simply waits for all threads to finish. If I don't have the loop, then when the subroutine ends, all threads terminate unfinished.

Comment: The ThreadPool works, but not when I run all 500 tests. I want to run, say, 10 tests at a time. So I need a queue. Parallel appears to offer the ability to limit the number of threads. Will it not do what I need? If not, I will look at other options. Thoughts?

Comment: If you have 500 distinct functions to run how would running them in a foreach work? Will they be in some `IEnumerable<Action>`?

Comment: What would you be iterating over if you were going to use a foreach loop?

Comment: Read the [MSDN Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop): Paraller.ForEach is to execute an action over an enumeration. Your code does not have an enumeration. Use the [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) class to execute several functions in parallel.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will look at the TASK class and create something that I can enumerate over (a list?). I assume that I can then connect the list to the ForEach. I will do more reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```vb
Dim subs() As Action = {
    AddressOf Test1,
    AddressOf Test2,
    AddressOf Test3
}
Parallel.ForEach(
    subs,
    Sub(item) item()
)
```

It may even be possible to build the action list using reflection, instead of hard-coding them, e.g.

```vb
Dim t = Me.GetType()
Dim subs = (
    From m In t.GetMethods()
    Where m.Name.StartsWith("Test")
    Select Sub() m.Invoke(Me, Nothing)
).ToList()
```